# Buttons with dynamic ajax text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my php page I have a row of buttons which each have some values (5 in this example). These values shall be send into a ajax script which do some calculation to values and return the result for each button without reloading the homepage. In this example the result will be

FRANK=5 (button 1)

FRANK=frank (button 2)

FRANK=48 (button 3)

FRANK=Bo (button 4)

FRANK=test (button 5)

When I press the first button I should see result 1 on the button. When I press the next button I should see result 2 on the button.

I only have one result returned on button 1 since all buttons has the same container for the return value. I need more containers for return values and I could add $i to the container: . This will give me different containers to return the result to. But how can I use $i in the javascript. My problem is also that var x in the javascript always will be the value from the first button. Again I could add $i to the id="x": id="x'.$i.'" but still I only have document.getElementById("x").value to read the x value in the javascript.

I hope that somebody help me to finish the code here.

Mainpage:

```
include('hide-ajax-scripts.php');

$dblinjer=Array();

$dblinjer[0]['loebid']=5;
$dblinjer[1]['loebid']='frank';
$dblinjer[2]['loebid']=48;
$dblinjer[3]['loebid']='Bo';
$dblinjer[4]['loebid']='test';

$i=0;
while($i<5){
    
    $dblinjer[$i]['nrlink']='<div><button type="button" id="x" value="'.$dblinjer[$i]['loebid'].'" onclick=baadimaal("baadimaal")><span id="container"></span></button></div>';
    echo $dblinjer[$i]['nrlink'];
    $i++;
}
```

hide-ajax-scripts.php contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function baadimaal(str) {
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value; //henter værdi fra input felt med id = x
//    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = x; //viser variablen para på pladsholder 
    
    
    
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML =
        this.responseText; //her placeres svaret, som kommer tilbage fra hide-ajax-svar filen
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "hide-ajax-svar.php?funk=" + str + "&para=" + x); //overfør str og x til hide-ajax-svar filen
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

hide-ajax-svar.php contains the calculation. Here will come a lot more calculations and storing of values in database.

```
<?php
if($funk=='baadimaal'){
    echo 'FRANK='.$para;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `this` inside your function call where `this` refer to current button which is clicked .Also , you cannot use same `ids` for mutliple elements instead use `class` selector . So, change your **php** code like below:

```
$dblinjer[$i]['nrlink']='<div><button type="button" value="'.$dblinjer[$i]['loebid'].'" onclick=baadimaal("baadimaal",this)><span class="container"></span></button></div>';
```

Then , add `this` as parameter inside your function and then use `el.value` to get the button value which is clicked and `el.querySelector(".container").innerHTML` to add result inside the span tag where button has been clicked. So, change your **js** code like below :

```
function baadimaal(str,el) {
    var x = el.value; //henter værdi fra input felt med id = x
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function() {
       el.querySelector(".container").innerHTML =
       this.responseText;
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "hide-ajax-svar.php?funk=" + str + "&para=" + x);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks at lot. That works for the input to the script. Can you also modify the code, so the return value will be shown on each button? Now, all return values goes to the first button.

Comment: No problem glad to help :) You can  [upvote and marked this as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking tick symbol .

Comment: I actually want the result to be return to another place on the homepage. This is not possible with your script. Can it be changed a little? Nrlinkres is wanted as result placeholder.

```
$i=0;
while($i<5){
    
    $dblinjer[$i]['nrlink']='<div><button type="button" id="'.$dblinjer[$i]['loebid'].'" value="'.$dblinjer[$i]['loebid'].'" onclick=baadimaal("baadimaal",this)></button></div>';
    $dblinjer[$i]['nrlinkres']='<span id="container'.$dblinjer[$i]['loebid'].'"></span>';
    echo $dblinjer[$i]['nrlink'].'-'.$dblinjer[$i]['nrlinkres'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You can asked another question for same will help you there currently this was not mention is question asked :) .

Comment: Ok, I will another question.

Comment: For some reason I can't ask anymore questions? I have reached the limit for questions its says.

Comment: I hope you will help me here. Sorry, that I couldn't format my code.

Comment: Please see my code below. I want the result to go back to another php variable $dblinjer[$i]['nrlinkres'] which I want to show next to the button. Please see example of php code below.

Comment: just get the attribute of button `var id = el.getAttribute("id")` and then change `el.querySelector(".container").innerHTML` to
`document.getElementById("container"+id).innerHTML`